# Xpath "preceding" check to find value

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

The html on which the Xpath is being applied is kind of long and hence pasting the link to the page on which the Xpath needs to be fired.

[http://www.amazon.com/Greatest-Hits-More-Dr-Hook/dp/B003ANZBD0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1424511706&sr=8-1&keywords=B003ANZBD0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ANZBD0)

I want to get the "Buy New" price of an item only if the item is "Fulfilled By Amazon".

I am using Html Agility Pack on C#.

Here is my attempt. I first try to see if the item is fulfilled by Amazon.
`//div[@id='buyNewInner']//descendant::a[contains(@href,'isAmazonFulfilled=1')]`

But I dont know how to continue from here to go to the preceding nodes and get the price of the item, in this case $99.99

Intention is not only have a single Xpath to get this price but also ensure I avoid as much as assumption possible on position of various nodes relative to each other and try to match w.r.t visible text rather than Html node positioning like `div//span[1]`. (Here the Xpath signifies match with first span - which I am trying to avoid if possible)

So in this case, the logic for matching I am trying to achieve is:

**Find the price following the words "Buy New" provided this occurs before the words "FulFillment By Amazon"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible XPath (formatted for readability), constructed based on your attempt to check whether the item is fulfilled by Amazon.

```
//div[
        @id='buyNewInner' 
            and 
        .//descendant::a[contains(@href,'isAmazonFulfilled=1')]
     ]
/preceding-sibling::div[@id='buyNewSection']
//span[contains(@class,'offer-price')]
```

First part of the XPath returns `<div id="buyNewInner">` element **only** if the item is "Fulfilled By Amazon" :

```
//div[
        @id='buyNewInner' 
            and 
        .//descendant::a[contains(@href,'isAmazonFulfilled=1')]
     ]
```

The next bit returns `<div id="buyNewSection">` which assumed to be located before `buyNewInner` div at the same level, hence we use `preceding-sibling` :

```
/preceding-sibling::div[@id='buyNewSection']
```

Then the last part goes straight to the `<span>` containing the item price :

```
//span[contains(@class,'offer-price')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **..** to go back to the father of the node. Using the example page you gave, adding **../../../../div[@id='buyNewSection']** brings you to the sibling **div** that you need. The XPath:

```
//div[@id='buyNewInner']//descendant::a[contains(@href,'isAmazonFulfilled=1')]/../../../../div[@id='buyNewSection']//span[contains(@class,'offer-price')]
```

will display

$99.99

Comment: Thx for your response. I am actually trying to avoid fixed number of such hardcodings `/../../../../` . If one parent misses to occur in any other type of page, this wont work. Thtas why I was checking `preceding` instead of fixed number of `/../`. Any ideas around that line?